# Multiple USB handheld barcode scanners. Which scanner gave input?

Tags: windows, barcode, user32

I'm working on a project where there are multiple handheld barcode scanners attached to one PC.
When they scan a barcode, I need to know which scanner scanned the barcode.

I tried using the Windows raw input API (`GetRawInputDeviceList`) but I don't manage to filter the handheld scanner this way.

Is there any other option I'm missing here?
I've read about virtual COM ports over USB, but I don't know if that would work in my situation?

I hope I'm not the only one who ever tried this :)
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Many scanners allow adding prefix and/or suffix strings to each scan.  You could assign a unique prefix to each scanner, which would allow identifying the source.